# Why do some properties need a default defined in the style before a DataTrigger takes effect?

Tags: wpf, xaml, dependency-properties

Why is it that some dependency properties need to have a default setter in the style before the triggered setters will take effect?

For example,

```
<ContentControl>

    <ContentControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DefaultTemplate">
            <TextBlock Text="Default Template" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="MouseOverTemplate">
            <TextBlock Text="MouseOver Template" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentControl.Resources>

    <ContentControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">

            <!-- Triggered setter will work without this default setter -->
            <!--<Setter Property="ContentTemplate" 
                        Value="{StaticResource DefaultTemplate}" />-->

            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" 
                            Value="{StaticResource MouseOverTemplate}" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>

        </Style>
    </ContentControl.Style>

</ContentControl>
```

I saw a good explanation of it somewhere, but I can't remember where. I recall it had something to do with [the order that WPF applies dependency property values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx), but I can't remember the details, or why some properties need the default defined before triggers will take effect, while others do not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be very surprised if your first `Style` does not work, unless your `ContentControl` is defined like:

```
<ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource DefaultTemplate}" />
```

If so, then it would have to do with value precedence. From your link, setting like in my example would be at #3. So the only thing that could override it would be an animation or if the value were coerced. Neither the `Style` or the `ControlTemplate` (if any) could change the `ContentControl.ContentTemplate` property.

With your second `Style`, you could define your `ContentControl` like so:

```
<ContentControl />
```

In this case, the `Setter` for `DefaultTemplate` is at #8 so the triggers can override it (as they are at #6).

Assuming again, that you have:

```
<ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource DefaultTemplate}" />
```

Then it is possible to override the `DataTemplate` used in the `ControlTemplate`, but you cannot change the `ContentControl.ContentTemplate`'s value. Something like:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
    <Setter Property="ControlTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="presenter" />
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SomeProperty}" Value="A">
                        <Setter TargetName="presenter" Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource TemplateA}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SomeProperty}" Value="B">
                        <Setter TargetName="presenter" Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource TemplateB}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Here, we switch the `DataTemplate` used by the ContentPresenter so it effectively ignores the `ContentControl.ContentTemplate` property.

Based on your updates though, there is nothing for the mouse to be "over". The ContentControl has not rendered anything (not even a transparent pixel), so it would not receive any mouse events. You can do something like this to correct it:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource MouseOverTemplate}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

And you'd need to set Background="Transparent" on the ContentControl.

Comment: The first style does not work. Give it a try with a simple `IsMouseOver` trigger.

Comment: @Rachel - How are you defining that trigger? This would not work `{Binding IsMouseOver}` as that applies to the DataContext, but this should work `{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}`.

Comment: Hrrm you're right about it not working in this case due to there being no content, but I have seen this behavior with other style setters. Let me see if I can find a better example.

Comment: I'm beginning to think I'm wrong. I know there's been multiple times where I've encountered triggers that weren't working unless I added the default style setter, although it's been a while since I last encountered that problem, and have since always added a default setter to my triggers. It's entirely possible that my XAML was flawed, or that it was a bug in an older version of the .Net framework. Accepting your answer for now since it seems more likely that the cause of my problems was flawed XAML, but if I find a good example of this problem I'm re-opening the question w/ a bounty :)